# Lambda Calculus Expression Evaluation

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am looking at the following lambda calculus expression: `(λx.(λy.(x(λx.xy))))y`. Could somebody help me to evaluate it? I am guessing that the first step would be to pass the outermost y into the outer most function λx, but I am unsure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have to rename the bound $y$ to $z$ to avoid capture:
$$(\lambda x.(\lambda z. (x(\lambda x.xz))))y$$
Then we may substitute $y$ for any bound occurence of $x$:
$$(\lambda z. (y(\lambda x.xz)))$$

Comment: Thanks. The process would be the same whether we do it in normal or applicative order, right?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Could you check this one out too? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363890/identifying-all-redexes-in-lambda-expression