# Identifying All Redexes in Lambda Expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am self-studying Lambda calculus and have encountered a question where I need to identify all the redexes of the following expression:  `(λu.(λx.u)u)((λy.y)(λw.(λv.v)w))`. Here are all the ones I've come up with, but I'm not sure if they are valid or if I'm missing any. Could somebody help?

```
1. (λx.(λy.y) (λw.(λv.v) w)) ((λy.y) (λw.(λv.v) w))
2. (λy.y) (λw.(λv.v) w)
3. λw.(λv.v) w
4. (λu.(λx.u) u) ((λy.y) (λv.v))
5. (λx.λv.v) (λv.v)
```

Comment: http://joerg.endrullis.de/lambdaCalculator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redex of a term is its subterm of the form $(\lambda x.M)N$. Some of your expressions aren't redexes of the given expression, but of some different terms (which you probably computed by evaluating the original one).

Redexes of the original expressions are:
$$
\underbrace{(\lambda u.\underbrace{(\lambda x.u)u})(\underbrace{(\lambda y.y)(\lambda w.\underbrace{(\lambda v.v)w})})}
$$

Comment: I see. So (λu.(λx.u)u) wouldn't be a redex then?

Comment: @JohnRoberts No, this term isn't a redex. But it _contains_ redex $(\lambda x.u)u$ as its subterm.

Answer (score 0):

In your list, the terms which appear are the following:
$$
y,\quad A = λy·y,\quad v,\quad B = λv·v,\quad w,\quad C_w = B w,\\
D = λw·C_w,\quad E = A D,\quad F = λx·E,\quad G = F E,\quad u,\quad H_u = λx·u,\\
I_u = H_u u,\quad J = λu·I_u,\quad K = A B,\quad L = J K,\quad M = λx·B,\quad N = M B.
$$
Your numbered expressions are, respectively, $G$, $E$, $D$, $L$ and $N$. The terms which are variables are:
$$y,\quad x,\quad w,\quad u.$$
The terms which are lambda-abstractions are:
$$
A = λy·y,\quad B = λv·v,\quad D = λw·C_w,\quad F = λx·E,\\
H_u = λx·u,\quad J = λu·I_u,\quad M = λx·B.
$$
The terms which are applications are
$$C_w = B w,\quad E = A D,\quad G = F E,\quad I_u = H_u u,\quad K = A B,\quad L = J K,\quad N = M B.
$$

An application whose first subterm is a lambda abstraction is a redex. All of the applications listed are of this form and are, therefore, redexes. Under β-reduction:
$$
C_w = (λv·v) w → w,\quad
E = (λy·y) D → D,\quad
G = (λx·E) E → E,\quad
I_u = (λx·u) u → u,\\
K = (λy·y) B → B,\quad
L = (λu·I_u) K → I_K,\quad
N = (λx·B) B → B.
$$
Thus,
$$C_w → w,\quad G → E → D,\quad L → I_K → K → B,\quad N → B.$$

The lambda abstractions reduce underneath their respective lambdas to:
$$D = λw·C_w → λw·w,\quad F = λx·E → λx·D,\quad J = λu·I_u → λu·u.$$
The others are all already in normal form. Thus, defining $O = λw·w$, we have:
$$G → D → O,\quad E → D → O,\quad D → O,\quad L → I_K → K → B,\quad N → B.$$
Finally, under α-equivalence, $A ≡ B ≡ O$.